# Array values are getting replaced by the last value being added in the array

Tags: arrays, c, stack

I am writing a basic c program where two people can interact with each other(send messages, read the messages sent by the other person etc.). I am using stacks to store the messages sent. But whenever I am trying to store multiple messages in the array, the previous messages are getting replaced by the last message stored. I am storing the messages sent by the first person in the array `arrayMsgs2` and vice versa.
So first I select the first person and send messages to the second person then I switch to the second person to check if the messages from the first person were received. But when I select the `unreadMessages2()` function (which I literally hard coded to check for the error), we get that all the previous messages have been replaced by the latest message.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int top = -1;
int top2 = -1;
int readMsg1=0;
int readMsg2=0;

char** arrayMsgs1;
char** arrayMsgs2;

void push1(char* message);
void push2(char* message);

char* allocateMemoryForMessage(char* msg)
{
    return (char*)malloc(strlen(msg)*sizeof(char));
}
//...................................................................................................................................for the first person
void sendMessageTo2(char* msg)
{

    arrayMsgs2[++top2] = allocateMemoryForMessage(msg);
    arrayMsgs2[top2] = msg;
    printf("\nStoring message in the index %d: %s",top2,arrayMsgs2[top2]);
    //push1(newMessage);
    return;

}

void push1(char* message)
{
    arrayMsgs2[++top2] = message;
    return;
}

void displayAllMessages1()
{
    if(top==-1) //..........................Checking if there are no messages
    {
        printf("\nNo messages to display");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=top;i++) {
        printf("\n%s", arrayMsgs1[i]);
    }

    readMsg1=top+1;  //........................To ensure all the messages are marked read.
    return;
}

void unreadMessages1()
{
    if(readMsg1>top)
    {
        printf("\nNo messages unread");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n%d Unread Messages",top - readMsg1 + 1);

    while(readMsg1<=top)
    {
        printf("\n%s",arrayMsgs1[readMsg1]);
        readMsg1++;
    }
}

//...............................................................................................................................For the second person
void sendMessageTo1(char* msg)
{
    char* newMessage = allocateMemoryForMessage(msg);
    newMessage = msg;
    push2(newMessage);

}

void push2(char* message)
{
    arrayMsgs1[++top] = message;
    return;
}

void displayAllMessages2()
{
    if(top2==-1) //.....................Checking if there are no messages
    {
        printf("\nNo messages to display");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=top2;i++) {
        printf("\n%s", arrayMsgs2[i]);
    }

    readMsg2=top+1;  //........................To ensure all the messages are marked read.
    return;
}

void unreadMessages2()
{
    if(readMsg2>top2)
    {
        printf("\nNo messages unread");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n%d Unread Message(s)",top2 - readMsg2 + 1);

    printf("\n%s",arrayMsgs2[0]);
    printf("\n%s",arrayMsgs2[1]);
}





int main()
{
arrayMsgs1 = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));    //................................allocating memory for the stack of messages
arrayMsgs2 = (char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char*));    //................................allocating memory for the stack of messages


int person;

printf("\nWhich person are you?(1 or 2) ");
scanf("%d",&person);



int choice;
do {
    printf("\n\n-----Menu-----");
    printf("\n1:Send a message");
    printf("\n2:Read unread messages");
    printf("\n3:Display all the messages recieved");
    printf("\n4:Switch Person");
    printf("\n5:Exit");
    printf("\n\nEnter your choice\n");
    scanf("\n%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:printf("\nEnter the message to send: \n");
        char messageToBeSent[100];
        scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", messageToBeSent);
        if(person==1)
            sendMessageTo2(messageToBeSent);
        else
            sendMessageTo1(messageToBeSent);
        break;
    case 2: if(person==1)
              unreadMessages1();
            else
              unreadMessages2();
        break;
    case 3: if(person==1)
                displayAllMessages1();
            else
                displayAllMessages2();
        break;
    case 4: if(person==1)
            {
                printf("\nSwitching to the second person.");
                person = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nSwitching to the first person.");
                person = 1;
            }
            break;
    case 5:printf("\nExited ");
        break;
    default:printf("\nPlease enter a value between 1 and 4");
        break;
    }
} while (choice != 5);

}
```

Comment: How many bytes do you need to store a string whose `strlen` is *n*?

Comment: `sendMessageTo2` correctly pushes your new memory onto the array, but then overwrites it with the original pointer.  That leaks your memory and causes this problem.  That is not how to copy strings.  Instead use `strncpy`.  You must also add 1 to the size when allocating memory because you must account for the null-terminator.  Unless you really need to split your code up so much, I suggest that the "allocate memory for string" function _also_ does the copy so the caller doesn't need to.

Comment: `arrayMsgs2[++top2] = allocateMemoryForMessage(msg); arrayMsgs2[top2] = msg;` That doesn't do what you think it does. It needs to be `char *msg_buf = allocateMemoryForMessage(msg); strcpy(msg_buf, msg)`. Also, the `malloc` needs an extra byte for the NUL terminator. Or more simply just use `arrayMsgs2[++top2] = strdup(msg)`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much guys